# Web Deploy to EC2 instances behind AWS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, webdeploy

I've just setup an elastic load balancer with a number of EC2 instances behind it running my web application.

I am currently deploying my web app using Web Deploy through Team City (to a non-load balaned environment). The package will also need to be parametrized at the time of deployment.

My problem is that running web deploy against an individual instance will obviously not update all instances behind the ELB.

Elastic Beanstalk is not an option as I need more than the Vanilla Windows Server instance to run my app.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk allows you to use custom AMI, which you can customize to your liking: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html

You can also customize many of the parameters of the *non-legacy* containers, even on Windows: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html

It is probably best to use Elastic Beanstalk, if you are already using it, as it has better integration to EC2 and other AWS resources. It is probably less likely that an MS tool will have the same level of support.

Comment: thank but I'm not using Beanstalk at the moment and the reason is that awsdeploy currently doesn't support parametrized deployments (like webdeploy does).

Answer (score 0):

We setup a DFS Replication for the wwwroot. We just web deploy to any one server and it gets replicated to the rest..